# Como mudar o botão(<button>) de "Ver senha" para uma imagem (<img>)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Existe um campo do cadastro de um funcionário chamado `senha` da qual existe um botão chamado `"Ver senha"` que permite ver a senha do usuário, só que eu quero retirar o botão `Ver senha` que fiz em javascript e queria saber como substituir esse `<button>` por um ícone chamado `olho.png` que combine melhor com o campo (questão de affordance).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title> Cadastrar Funcionário </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/WEB/css/css.css">
    <script>
        function mostrarSenha(){
            var tipo = document.getElementById("senha")
            if (tipo.type == "password") {
                tipo.type = "text";
            }else{
                tipo.type = "password";
            }
        }
    </script> 
</head>
<body> 

    <form method="POST">
        <p> Senha: <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" size=30 maxlength="32" required="">
        <button type="button" onclick="mostrarSenha()"> Ver senha</button> </p>
    </form>
```

```
caminho da imagem da qual eu quero substituir o <button> por um <img>: img/olho.png
```

Comment: pq não coloca `background: url('img/olho.png')` no css que define o botão?

Comment: Tem como me demonstrar em código?

Comment: sim, veja a resposta

Comment: Se entendi o que você quer fazer, acho uma solução com svg mais agradável, como [essa](https://codepen.io/maxpelic/pen/gygLxm). Quando precisei fazer, usei isso como referência e adaptei pra minha necessidade :)

Comment: @RafaelTavares interessante esse código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode definir uma imagem como *background* do botão, assim:

```js
function mostrarSenha() {
   document.getElementById('senha').type = 'text';
}
```

```css
.btn-senha {
   background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/mono-general-4/16/eye-icon.png') no-repeat;
   width: 18px;
   height: 18px;
}
```

```html
 <p> 
    Senha: <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" size=30 maxlength="32" required="">
    <button class="btn-senha" type="button" onclick="mostrarSenha()"></button>
 </p>
```

Comment: Os dois primeiros códigos ficam no CSS?

Comment: No ```Executar``` de seu código não oculta a senha

Comment: se digitar uma senha e apertar o botão ele exibe a senha. veja que no meu exemplo mudei o type de "password" para "text". Não conseguiu identificar o código? precisa estudar isso @Fujjin :) o primeiro é javascript, o segundo é css

Comment: Ricardo, acho que ele quer que alterne entre mostrar/ocultar ao clicar no ícone ;0

Comment: eu pensei nisso @Sam mas pelo texto *"só que eu quero retirar o botão Ver senha"* não dá pra ter certeza.. de qualquer forma, era só estilo, no exemplo ainda foi "grátis" o exibir senha ;)

Comment: O texto diz uma coisa mas o código mostra um if...else alternando o type entre text/password. Mas tá tranquilo.

Comment: sim, o core mesmo da resposta é o `background`, que tá passando quase desapercebido :)